# Как дополнить исходную строку используя конкатенацию?

Tags: python

Выведите на печать содержимое объекта класса Quest.
Для этого переопределите метод **str** в классе Quest. По умолчанию он должен возвращать строку

```
'Цель квеста {название_квеста} — {цель_квеста}.'
```

При определённых условиях строка должна выглядеть иначе:

> если квест уже завершён —

```
'Цель квеста {название_квеста} — {цель_квеста}. Квест завершён.'
```

> если квест уже принят на исполнение —

```
'Цель квеста {название_квеста} — {цель_квеста}. Квест выполняется.'
```

```
import datetime as dt
import time

class Quest:
    def __init__(self, name, description, goal):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.goal = goal
        self.start_time = None
        self.end_time = None

    def accept_quest(self):
        if self.end_time:
            return 'С этим испытанием вы уже справились.'
        self.start_time = dt.datetime.now()
        return f'Начало квеста "{self.name}" положено.'

    def pass_quest(self):
        if not self.start_time:
            return 'Нельзя завершить то, что не имеет начала!'
        self.end_time = dt.datetime.now()
        completion_time = self.end_time - self.start_time
        return (f'Квест "{self.name}" окончен.'
                f' Время выполнения квеста {completion_time}')

    # Напишите код метода __str__.
    def __str__(self):
        # если квест уже завершён
        if self.goal == self.end_time:
            return(f'Цель квеста {self.name} — {self.goal}. Квест завершён.')
        # если квест уже принят на исполнение
        if self.goal == self.start_time:
            return (f'Цель квеста {self.name} — {self.goal}. Квест выполняется.')
        # По умолчанию он должен возвращать строку
        return (f'Цель квеста {self.name} - {self.goal}')


quest_name = 'Сбор пиксельники'
quest_goal = 'Соберите 12 ягод пиксельники.'
quest_description = '''
В древнем лесу Кодоборье растёт ягода "пиксельника".
Она нужна для приготовления целебных снадобий.
Соберите 12 ягод пиксельники.'''

new_quest = Quest(quest_name, quest_description, quest_goal) 

print(new_quest.pass_quest())
print(new_quest.accept_quest())
time.sleep(3)
print(new_quest.pass_quest())
print(new_quest.accept_quest())

# Печатаем объекта класса Quest:
print(new_quest)
```

> Подскажите, как мне реализовать конкатенацию для метода **str**. Перепробовал все возможные варианты. Есть представление как это должно быть реализовано, но пока ни нашел ни чего подходящего.

Comment: В коде я описал условие исходя из задания. Т.е. метод __str__. Я изначально думал написать метод __str__  который  по умолчанию возвращает строку  'Цель квеста {название_квеста} — {цель_квеста}.' в классе Quest. И создать еще один класс который будет наследоваться от класса Quest и переопределит метод __str__ другим методом в котором я буду манипулировать условиями при котором будет менять вывод строки в основном методе __str__ класса Quest. Но пока уменя ни чего невыходит.

Comment: string + string1 +string2

Comment: В переопределёном __str__ выполняйте, условия которые требует ТЗ. То есть if elif elif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
    # если квест уже завершён
    if self.end_time:
        return(f'Цель квеста {self.name} — {self.goal}. Квест завершён.')
    # если квест уже принят на исполнение
    if self.start_time and not self.end_time:
        return (f'Цель квеста {self.name} — {self.goal}. Квест выполняется.')
    # По умолчанию он должен возвращать строку
    return (f'Цель квеста {self.name} - {self.goal}')
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Этот ответ решил мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    res = f'Цель квеста {self.name} - {self.goal}'
    if self.end_time:
        res += ' Квест завершён.'
    elif self.start_time and self.end_time is None:
        res += ' Квест выполняется.'
    return res
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]